# Using rasterio (python) in Visual Studio Code - "does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name."

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, gdal, rasterio

I am trying to use rasterio in Visual Studio Code for Windows. I downloaded the rasterio and GDAL binaries from: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) and installed them using "py -m pip install ". Visual Studio Code says the packages are installed, however when I go to run the "open" function for rasterio, it gives me the following error

"rasterio._err.CPLE_OpenFailedError: does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name."

Even though the file does exist in the location I am specifying, and is a .tif file.

I have created a virtual environment and installed the binaries within it, which did not help the problem.

I am relatively new to coding, so apologies if this isn't specific enough/let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with `rasterio` using VS code. However, now I'm executing the code straight from the console (windows terminal + conda environment) and I don't have any issue.